# Configure multiple consumers for amqp in mule esb

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, mule, esb

I have the following configuration to create a connector for rabbitMQ in mule but the problem is that only one consumer is created, I was wondering if its possible to configure mule to create more than one consumer at a time.

```
 <amqp:connector name="amqpfiledetailConnector" 
                host="${rabbitmq.host}" 
                port="${rabbitmq.port}" 
                username="${rabbitmq.username}" 
                password="${rabbitmq.password}" 
                activeDeclarationsOnly="false" />
```

I was able to achieve the multiple consumer creation using Spring framework but that means the entry point to the application will be a Java class(except if there is a way to transfer the request back to mule once the message has been read from the queue). I want to start the flow from mule so at to do other things.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.6.0 AMQP transport supports numberOfConsumers, here is the [doc reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/amqp-connector-reference). For example:

```
<amqp:connector name="amqpfiledetailConnector" 
                host="${rabbitmq.host}" 
                port="${rabbitmq.port}" 
                username="${rabbitmq.username}" 
                password="${rabbitmq.password}" 
                numberOfConsumers="4"
                activeDeclarationsOnly="false" />
```

Comment: Tried that but thriws exception while deploying that the flag wasn't supported.

Comment: Check the version of the transport you are using.  Usually that is set in the maven pom.xml.